# Does 'android:animateLayoutChanges="true" ' Still work

Tags: android

I saw that this statement used inside an xml layout will automate animations for you. I want to add this to my app, but when I put it in the layout I want

```
   <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/arrow_background"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/format_help">
```

And then I change the visibility to gone

```
view.findViewById(R.id.format_help).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It only just instantly goes away. The information I saw about this was from a few years ago so does anyone know if this is still supposed to work or how to get it to work?

EDIT: Also I added this statement everywhere and it still does not working. If it matters this is inside a fragment/dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for views inside container which has the property android:animateLayoutChanges="true". If a Linear layout having the above property, whenever a new view added or removed from that container the effect is visible. The animation effect will not be visible to the container itself when container is added or removed. For more information check the below link.[usage of animateLayoutChanges](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)